# Run the file in folder called `python` not the python interpreter

Tags: bash, python, gnome-terminal

I have a folder. Inside of this folder is an executable called `python`. When I try to run `python` from the terminal it instead runs the python interpreter. **How can I run the file called python?**

Comment: Close voters: This is a very different question than "how do I add a directory to my path" although the answers to that may help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the path. If you're in the directory with the binary, that's as simple as:

```
./python
```

Or yes, do as Muru suggested and add it to the path. That said, changing the path could interfere with how applications (running under your user) call Python. If you deflect them to the wrong version, they may function incorrectly.

There is not a good way to override the global `python`.
It *should* point to the version that ships with Ubuntu.

Comment: rather confused about your last comment.  Virtualenv is a great way to override the global python

Comment: `virtualenv` path replacements are temporary though. You load them up for your session and then you deactivate them. They shouldn't affect things in other sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the other answers you can also use the full path to the executable. For example, if your **python** executable is in **/home/user/some_dir/python** then running the following command from in the terminal will do the job:

```
user@user-home:~$ /home/user/some_dir/python
```

For ease of use you can create an alias for the above command so that you don't have to type the full path every time, by just appending the it in your **.bashrc** file. To do so, run the following commands in the terminal:

```
user@user-home:~$ echo "alias local_python=/home/user/some_dir/python" >> /home/user/.bashrc 
user@user-home:~$ source /home/user/.bashrc
```

****Important note: Here i have used **local_python** as the alias name, you can choose any name you want but don't use **python** or any other already installed binaries' names as name of the alias.